# How do I convert NSString to const void

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I am currently having issues converting `NSString` to a `const void *`

Here is my code:

```
DoSomethingFunction:(const void *)parameter

 [class DoSomeThingFunction:(const void *)passswordField.text]
```

Password field is a `UITextfield`. The value becomes null when I try and cast it.

I want `passwordField.text` to be a `const void *` so it can be used in the function.

Comment: Can you post more code ?

Comment: A pointer does *not* become null by casting ...

Comment: @KudoCC Why? This explains what they are after pretty well, they are trying to pass `passwordField.text` to a `const void *` Why does he need to share more code.

Comment: @Popeye Casting the pointer won't cause it be null. So need more relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try casting the result of one of the NSString's methods that return a C string:

```
– cStringUsingEncoding:
– getCString:maxLength:encoding:
– UTF8String
```

[NSString Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/UTF8String)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on function implementation. It can be like this:

```
NSString *string = @"text";
const void *parameter = CFBridgingRetain(string);
DoSomethingFunction(parameter);
```

If function has similar parameter handling

```
void DoSomethingFunction(const void *parameter) {
    NSString *string = CFBridgingRelease(parameter);
    NSLog(@"%@", string);
}
```

Comment: NSString *string = CFBridgingRelease(parameter);
    NSLog(@"%@", string);

Bad Access